# Need to test upload multiple file (CSV) with the multiple Vuser in the Jmeter script

Tags: jmeter

I have scenario
Step#1 Login to the Application
Step#2 Search the Submission Number
Step#3 Go to the Account Detail
Step#4 Browse the file from the your system
Step#5 Click on the Submit button

I am able to do the same by the single user.
Need to do the same task through the multiple user.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For parametrisation using single CSV file - use [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
- For parametrisation using multiple CSV files - use [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) function
- If you need to simulate file upload with JMeter - use "Send Files With the Request" section of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

  [image: HTTP Request upload file]

See [Performance testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) guide for detailed information on how to perform file upload and download with JMeter

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for sharing the experience